# How can I tweak padding in UI elements?

Tags: gui, gtk, eclipse

Is there a way to tweak the amount of padding inside UI elements in Ubuntu, besides installing a different gtk theme?

This is how eclipse looks in Ubuntu (with the Radiance theme)

[image: Crop of eclipse in Ubuntu]

And this is how it looks on XP

[image: Crop of eclipse in Windows Xp]

What I would like to do is reduce the padding around the icons in the toolbar or the padding around text in tabs. Is there an app or some config file I could edit?

Comment: No solution for your problem, but I agree Eclipse looks horrible.

Comment: Your images are not loading but I know that eclipse doesn't look great on Linux. Its been an age old problem and the gtk hacks break other UI of other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if this solution works for you.

http://blog.sarathonline.com/2008/10/solved-eclipse-looks-good-in-ubuntu-now.html

Its specific to Eclipse.

Personally, I am now used to Eclipse in Ubuntu now after an upgrade to 24" LCD and reduced font size :)

Comment: yeah, a huge monitor would be an option, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [somewhat outdated theming tutorial](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes) on the GNOME wiki that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Colour Chooser appears to be able to alter padding on buttons etc. its available from the software centre.