# Gnome (or maybe unity?) ignoring gtkrc settings

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, gtkrc

This is related to the [recurring "white on black tooltips" question](https://askubuntu.com/q/70599/1645). Until yesterday I was able to change tooltip colors (and [fix UI element padding](https://askubuntu.com/q/10217/1645)) using a specific gtkrc file for eclipse, as suggested by [this blog post](http://blog.sarathonline.com/2008/10/solved-eclipse-looks-good-in-ubuntu-now.html).

My gtkrc looks like (slightly reformatted)

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\n
  tooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\n
  selected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\n
  bg_color:#F2F1F0\ntooltip_bg_color:#f5f5b5\nlink_color:#DD4814
...
```

and I run eclipse with the command

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.themes/eclipse.gtkrc eclipse
```

This worked fine for 11.10 and still works on 12.04, with the exception of tooltip colors, i.e. eclipse starts with the tweaked UI elements but still uses the default white on black tooltips.

Editing the system-wide gtkrc file at

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70665/1645) works fine, but I'd rather not do it and besides I still have no clue as to why eclipse will pick up all my modifications to gtkrc except the `gtk-color-scheme` setting. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: i suspect this is related to a switch from gtk2 to gtk3, but i couldn't say for sure

Answer (score 1):

Check content of gtk-3.0/gtk.css in selected theme directory.
As aking1012 said already, GTK3 used instead of GTK2.

Comment: Could be, but then how would I go about using an application specific gtkrc?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your gtkrc (either ~/.gtkrc-2.0 or your custom eclipse one):

```
style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = "#FFFFAF"
  fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
```

This is what gnome-color-chooser does, it works.