# Are there any tweaks for fixing the appearance of Eclipse Juno on ubuntu?

Tags: unity, eclipse, gtk3

As [we have previously established](https://askubuntu.com/q/10217/1645) ;-) running Eclipse on ubuntu is a bit *disappointing* on the UI side. Things are even worse now that Juno is out. Are there any tweaks specific to Gtk3 and Juno that help make things better?

The new UI maybe needs some getting used to, but I'm not convinced. Padding got much worse with all the extra (useless?) space between panes. The gradient on the toolbar looks ugly, the quick search looks like it needs some more polish, the buttons to switch perspectives maybe would look nicer without the quick search bar, tabs are waaay to big. Not sure the color scheme has been fixed since I'm running a modified theme for the sake of old 3.7 (the infamous white on black tooltips)

Comment: Could you sum up which things disappoint you? I'm using Juno as well and am actually quite happy with the UI things, especially because mouse overs are now readable without further tweaking. Is it the padding that bothers you?

Comment: The new UI maybe needs some getting used to, but I'm not convinced. Padding got much worse with all the extra (useless?) space between panes. The gradient on the toolbar looks ugly, the quick search looks like it needs some more polish, the buttons to switch perspectives maybe would look nicer without the quick search bar, tabs are waaay to big. Not sure the color scheme has been fixed since I'm running a modified theme for the sake of old 3.7 (the infamous white on black tooltips).

Comment: The good news is that the tooltips are working well now. No more black text on black tooltips. I, too, am still using a custom colour scheme to fix the background colours.
I recall seeing a guide to decrease the padding on 3.7, have you tried something like this for Juno:
http://xmemory.tompium.com/2012/01/make-eclipse-look-better-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I like is using [jeeeyul's eclipse-themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes).

Answer (score 8):

You may switch to classic Theme in the menu: Window->Preferences->General->Appearance.
This will get you back to the looks in eclipse 3.7 if you find that more appealing.

Comment: Ah, saved me from the very broken layout in Lubuntu (lot of stuff supposed to be grey were just white areas, etc). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**For Linux Mint Users (and maybe others too):**

This is a fix for this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1168281

Answer (score 2):

This next CSS modifications make the tabs much smaller:

```
$ vi /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/css/e4_default_gtk.css
.MPartStack {
    font-size: 8;
    font-family: Liberation Sans;
    swt-tab-renderer: null;
    swt-tab-height: 22px;
    swt-selected-tabs-background: #FFFFFF #ECE9D8 100%;
    swt-simple: true;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

The problem with that is that the buttons of the tabbed panel (maximize, minimize, etc) will become tiny. That happens when *swt-tab-height < 30*. If anybody knows how to resize those buttons. They are huge and force the tab height to minimum of 30!

Answer (score -2):

Hi make the definition in the e4_basestyle.css for .MPartStack{}

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please add more details to your answer ? It is helpful to not only OP but also to future readers.